# Microsoft graph Get Calls Data Not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

Can we get Microsoft Teams call data through Microsoft Graph API ???

The call may be through a teams meeting link provided in the meeting invite.

I would like to get the start time and end time of the call.

I have tried following queries

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/calls/

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/onlineMeetings

Answer (score 1):

You could use this Microsoft Graph API - [`Get onlineMeeting`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), the `startDateTime` and `endDateTime` will be included in the [response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1).

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/onlineMeetings/?$filter=VideoTeleconferenceId%20eq%20'123456789'
```

Note the [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions), it just supports the `Application` permission what means you can only use [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token, then use the token to call the API.

For more details about how to get the token and call the API, follow this link - [**Get access without a user**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service).

Comment: @ Joy Wang, Thanks for answering my query.
I am using postman and graph explorer(https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#) to test my queries. I could get the access token. However, don't know how to use the access token in fetching the online meetings.
Also, as suggested by you in the above query how do I get the VideoTeleconferenceId (filter=VideoTeleconferenceId%20eq%20'123456789')

Comment: @user2416427 As I mentioned, you just could use the client credential flow to get the token, follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service) to register an AD app, give the `OnlineMeetings.Read.All` permission, then get the token, use the token to call the API. You could not use graph explorer.

Comment: @user2416427 And about the `VideoTeleconferenceId`, check this line in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) : **The GET method is currently only supported for a [VTC conference id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/cloud-video-interop-for-teams-set-up). These IDs are generated for Cloud-Video-Interop licensed users and this method is used to get the details to join the meeting.**

Comment: Moved on to different task. Will update once I am back again